# xgboost cross validation - accuracy metrics

Tags: python, machine-learning, classification, xgboost, cross-validation

I'm doing cross validation on xgboost. Here is my code.

```
from xgboost import cv

xgb_cv = cv(dtrain=data_dmatrix, 
            params=params, 
            nfold=10,
            num_boost_round=50, 
            early_stopping_rounds=10, 
            metrics="auc", 
            as_pandas=True, 
            seed=1)
```

Is there any way to have "accuracy" metrics?

I couldn't find any "accuracy" option for "metrics" in [the documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/xgboost/versions/1.5.2.1/topics/xgb.cv).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The accuracy is 1 - the error rate (`metrics = 'error'`).